# How to refresh internet connection thats gets closed after every hour?

Tags: internet

I am in a hotel, where the internet connection has to be refreshed every hour. So after every hour a web page comes up and I have to click on a continue button and then continue to surf.

How can i automate this refreshing, because I keep things for download and they stop after one hour.

Any program / tool that can help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115).

Answer (score 1):

maybe by this: http://www.pagereboot.com/

Answer (score 0):

you could possibly use autohotkey and make a script to click on that certain place every 59 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a twill script (http://twill.idyll.org/) that submits the form automatically and cron/schedule it to run every hour.

That said, they're probably doing that to stop guys like you from setting up a big download!